# Desired State Configuration can't get hash table from Script resource Get block

Tags: powershell, hashtable, dsc

I have tested this using the built in Script resource from 1.1 as well as xScript 5.1.0.0 and get the same results. My Set and Test blocks work fine. I'm using several other script resources that are very similar and they work fine as well for the get block.

I've tried a lot of variations in syntax but it always comes back the same. I know the block is running because I commented out the line where the file which gets created gets removed and I see the file. I also ran this as a function in powershell and piped the output to Get-Member and can see it is indeed a hastable that is returned.

*On a side note, I really don't like the method I'm using here to manage this setting through DSC. I'm open to other ideas as long as it is still within DSC.*

```
Script StorePasswordsUsingReversibleEncyption
{
    SetScript   = {
        secedit /export /cfg c:\temp\secpol.cfg
        (gc C:\temp\secpol.cfg).replace("ClearTextPassword = 1", "ClearTextPassword = 0") | Out-File C:\temp\secpol.cfg
        secedit /configure /db c:\windows\security\local.sdb /cfg c:\temp\secpol.cfg /areas SECURITYPOLICY /quiet
        rm -force c:\temp\secpol.cfg -confirm:$false
    } 

    TestScript = {
        secedit /export /cfg c:\temp\secpol.cfg
        $str = (Get-Content 'c:\temp\secpol.cfg' | select-String 'ClearTextPassword' -SimpleMatch).ToString()
        rm -force c:\temp\secpol.cfg -confirm:$false
        if ($str -eq 'ClearTextPassword = 0') {return $true}
        else {return $false}            
    } 

    # Not working yet           
    GetScript   = {
        secedit /export /cfg c:\temp\secpol.cfg
        $str = (Get-Content 'c:\temp\secpol.cfg' | select-String 'ClearTextPassword' -SimpleMatch).ToString()
        rm -force c:\temp\secpol.cfg -confirm:$false
        return @{Result = $str}     
    }    
}
```

After I run Get-DSCConfiguration, the output returned in console is this:

```
Get-DscConfiguration : PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_ScriptResource  failed to execute Get-TargetResource functionality 
with error message: Failure to get the results from the script in a hash table format. 
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-DscConfiguration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager:root/Microsoft/...gurationManager)  
   [Get-DscConfiguration], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderOperationExecutionFailure,Get-DscConfiguration
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 GetScript   = {
        $null = secedit /export /cfg c:\temp\secpol.cfg
        $str = (Get-Content 'c:\temp\secpol.cfg' | select-String 'ClearTextPassword' -SimpleMatch).ToString()
        rm -force c:\temp\secpol.cfg -confirm:$false
        return @{Result = $str}     
    }
```

The problem is that when you call an external command (like `secedit`), everything it writes to stdout is returned as output if this command (and that's pretty natural). But if don't catch it into a variable, it will be passed further to the output of your script block. The [`return` statement](http://ss64.com/ps/return.html) is also a little misleading - it doesn't mean "return this thing only", but "write this thing to output stream, then return".

This means that your original `GetScript` doesn't return a single hashtable, but rather an arraythat looks like this:

```
@(
  "some-output-from-secedit",
  @{ Result = $str }
)
```

Assigning the output from external commands to a variable (I used `$null` in this case to denote I want to discard it) will prevent it from cluttering your script block's output.

Another way would be to redirect command's output to `Write-Verbose` (if you're interested in reading it) or to `$null` (if you don't care):

```
secedit /export /cfg c:\temp\secpol.cfg | write-verbose
```

Comment: Just a small side comment: I doubt that `rm` (alias for `Remove-Item`) will return anything w/o `-PassThru` parameter. +1 anyway.

Comment: This works, but I don't fully understand your explanation. Can you please link me to some documentation that may help me understand better? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

can you try modifying your getscript block like this:

```
GetScript   = {

start-process secedit -ArgumentList '/export /cfg c:\temp\secpol.cfg' -Wait
$str = (Get-Content 'c:\temp\secpol.cfg' | select-String 'ClearTextPassword' -SimpleMatch).ToString()
rm -force c:\temp\secpol.cfg -confirm:$false
return @{Result = $str}     
}
```